# Tensorflow summaries when using queues and scope reuse

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

In most cases, I'm using a single network instance with two different feed_dicts, one for the training data and one for the validation data. In this case I get both plots on a single graph. However, in the case of queues, I'm using two network instances (with scope reuse variables) which leads to two different summaries in Tensorboard, a graph for the validation data and another one for the training data. Does anyone know how to merge the two?

The question is somewhat similar to:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7089
but there they're also using a feed_dict

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try having two separate `FileWriter` instances that point to sibling directories. When TensorBoard scans the parent directory, it'll consider each subdirectory an independent Run and chart them together for comparison.

Comment: Cheers for the answer. I'm already doing this and it doesn't change the fact that I get "accuracy" for the training data and "accuracy_1" for the validation data

Comment: Maybe that happens because they're part of the same `GraphDef`. A quick workaround might be using slashes in the tag name you pass to the scalar summary function, e.g. `foo/accuracy` and `bar/accuracy`.